# ASP.NET MVC - Abstraction between Data and Object Layers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dbcontext

I am using ASP.NET EntityFramework MVC (All Latest) with Visual Studio 2013.

I am attempting to come up with a unifying means of standardizing the abstraction between my object and data layer.

I know that many people like to use the IRepository pattern with MVC.  My biggest issue with this is that it forces you to create and maintain a second object type (The Repository) for each of the objects that you want to maintain.  My solution has been to combing the IRepository method with a Static Factory pattern to make a Static Repository, for instance:

```
public class SiteDatabase : DbContext
{
    // Singleton
    private static SiteDatabase _Instance;
    public static SiteDatabase Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_Instance == null)
            {
                _Instance = new SiteDatabase();
            }
            return _Instance;
        }
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

}


public class User : IUser
{
    public static User Create(string UserName)
    {
        User item = new User();
        item.UserName = UserName;
        SiteDatabase.Instance.Users.Add(item);
        return item;
    }

    public static User Find(string UserName)
    {
        return SiteDatabase.Instance.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserName == UserName);
    }

    public static User[] All()
    {
        return SiteDatabase.Instance.Users.ToArray();
    }


    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    protected User()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    public void Delete()
    {
        SiteDatabase.Instance.Users.Remove(this);
    }
}

public class Page
{
    public static Page Create(string PageName)
    {
        ...
    }

    public static Page Find(string PageName)
    {
        ...
    }

    public static Page[] All()
    {
        ...
    }

    ...

    public void Delete()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

My question is: will this pattern cause me to miss out on any built-in functionality that the normal repository pattern would allow me to capture?

The non-static methods could be handled with an interface, but what about the static methods?  Is there any way to have a base class that ensures that static methods will exist in derived classes?

Comment: Looks like a nightmare to unit test this. Also it's wrong to think that you should create a Repository for each of your entities. In reality you should have a Repository per aggregate root.

Comment: You can create a generic repository which would work with all of your classes to add/delete/create/find from your database.

Comment: In addition to what others said, you should also consider using `lock` when implementing a Singleton pattern (I'm referring to SiteDatabase.Instance)

Comment: you mean like an object lock for threading?

Comment: @MohamadBataineh - But what about logic specific to individual models?  For instance, you might want to avoid adding a user when there is already a user with the specified UserName, but for a page you might allow duplicate page names -

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Why would it be a nightmare to unit test?  If you create a seperate repository class that you instantiate, I would think that you would normally only have a single instance of it system wide at any given time (within the controller) - so it is effectively the same as a static class then, no?

Comment: @William You can inherit the generic repository and create another one called myClassRepository where you can add whatever you want without losing functionality.

Comment: A singleton DBContext means all requests are sharing the same context. So that context will grow to become huge with all the objects you will store in it. Really unscalable.

Comment: Another issue is when you combine this with async/await. Assuming you have that singleton instance with locking, your app will slow down due to waiting for other processes to finish with their usage of the context instead of making their own, making async/await pretty useless.

Comment: @Shoe you mean it will become too large with too many object types or instances?  If it becomes too large because of too many types, I can always create a second type of DbContext with a separate set of DbEntities, right?  And if you are referring to too many instances - the actual query won't execute on the object until after I do a ToList() (or some such method due to lazy loading) - so I don't see how that would matter.  Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Shoe - in terms of async/await - this might be an issue - I don't know enough about multi-threading websites to comment on this.  Do users in different sessions share the same ApplicationContext?  i.e. someone views a site and i lock a variable, does someone else viewing the site in a different location have to wait for that lock to be released until it can be read?

Comment: @William With static variables, yes. Which is why it's best practice not to use them.

Comment: @Shoe but regardless, I mean I can always pass in a DbContext to the static CRUD methods that are within the objects - in that case, do you think the above model works?  My issues is that with a generic repository you might do something like Create(User user); where you pass in the User object to create but then you aren't controlling which properties are required to create the user in the first place -

Comment: @William You could, but then every CRUD method needs that parameter. That's less than ideal.